# JPA criteria GROUP BY dont add in SQL

Tags: java, jpa, group-by, criteria

I just try to get some entities from SQL DB with JPA criteria, but the GROUP BY close is never added in my SQL output

What i do :

```
final EntityManager em = getEntityManager();

final CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(sqlType);
final Root<T> root = criteriaQuery.from(sqlType);
criteriaQuery.select(root);

final String theaterId = "0E9390C6-57BB-4FE7-997B-2805C42A8EA7";
final String theaterId2 = "4D0462FC-8854-40CA-98F4-89E834A9FFA3";
criteriaQuery.where(root.get("contentLocations").get("theaterId").in(theaterId, theaterId2));
criteriaQuery.groupBy(root.get("id"));
criteriaQuery.having(cb.equal(cb.count(root.get("id")), 2));

final TypedQuery<T> q = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
final List<T> items = q.getResultList();
```

And what i get :

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.CONTENTID, t1.CREATED, t1.SEARCHFIELD, t1.TYPE, t1.UPDATED FROM tmsContentLocations t0, tmsContents t1 WHERE ((t0.THEATERID IN (?, ?)) AND (t0.tms_content_fk = t1.ID))
bind => [3D877C4B-89B2-7BB4-3590-C0A5F930FC64, B07833DD-9239-6E34-3D70-7726A6995E6C]
```

If I try this in a SQL query tool, it work, and if i manualy add "GROUP BY t1.id", it work as I expect from JPA.

What does I miss here ?

Thx

Edit : Added having statement in sample.
The point here is listing all my T where contentLocations contains every theaterId in my list
Work perfectly well in SQL

Comment: whats the point of groupBy without any aggregate function?

Comment: You'r right, I forgot this point. This is just a sample, in fact, I have an HAVING close
    `criteriaQuery.having(cb.equal(cb.count(root.get("id")), 2));`

right after the groupBy